# Invalid syntax error when attempting to use hypexport (hypothes.is)

Tags: python, export

I am trying to export my annotations through this method because the export tool isn't working for me. After some fiddling around I got hypexport to install. However this next step is giving me issues, any idea why?
[image]

Instructions are here: https://github.com/karlicoss/hypexport

Comment: You are attempting to run a command within your code. That's intended to be run from an OS terminal or command line. Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Put the relevant information in the question as text, not links to off-site images.

Comment: I ran it but now it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' even though it's installed

Comment: @redwood It means your module is not in your Python PATH. More information here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Comment: Please put your code textually in your post and add more context about how you are attempting to run your code (it seems you are in a notebook?)